# Is there a faster way to get data from a SQL Server database with Python?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.7

I am newbie software developer and I am trying to improve system for reports which I am using.

Problem is, I have data in a SQL Server table, with a few million rows and 10-15 columns.

Devices are sending data every 20 seconds to the database with datetime, deviceid, value and some other things.

This is how I tried to solved this problem with Python:

```
    while plus_10 < endTime:    
        query= 'SELECT TOP 1 [DateTime],[Value] FROM [tblName] WHERE [DeviceId] = {0} and [DateTime] >= \'{1}\''.format(device,plus_10)
        df1 = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
        if not df1.empty:
            date = (df1.iloc[0]['DateTime'])
            value = (df1.iloc[0]['Value'])
            colA = 'A{0}'.format(counter)
            colB= 'B{0}'.format(counter)
            sheet[colA] = date
            sheet[colA].alignment = alg2
            sheet[colA].border = brd
            sheet[colB] = value 
            sheet[colB].alignment = alg3
            sheet[colB].border = brd
            counter += 1
        plus_10 = date + timedelta(minutes = 10)
```

So, I have a `while` loop and query inside it. I am looking for TOP 1 time, and after I report to Excel, I am increasing last time for 10 minutes. When my current time (`plus_10`) is higher that endTime (15:00), the report will be done.

With this way, my program is working, but problem is time taken to generate the report. It takes 20-30 seconds every time I call the query because the database has a few million rows (can't be lower!) and I'm searching by datetime.

From 08:00 - 15:00 it takes over 20 minutes to generate.

Can I somehow improve my query or maybe something in my python code? I know that searching million rows by datetime is slower than search by ID, but I do not know how to solve this.

Thanks in advance for help. :=)

Comment: I'd test a couple of different queries in SQL Server and look at the execution plans. There is no order by in your TOP query - that worries me.
Other option would be using MAX([DateTime]) within your where clause as a sub query.

Comment: Hi, i've tried with order by tableID and with DateTime but is is the same. Query is executing 20-30 seconds from MS SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include your table's schema and any indexes on it?